# Modify php to run only if meta description field was blank and pull 2 sentences (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

I have the following PHP code in Magento which so far takes the first sentence of the description and makes it the meta description.

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_product')) : ?>
<?php if (strip_tags(str_replace("<br />",", ",substr(Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(), 0, strpos(Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(), '.')+1)))=="") : ?>
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="'.htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()).'" />' ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="'.strip_tags(str_replace("<br />",", ",substr(Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(), 0, strpos(Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(), '.')+1))).'" />' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="'.htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()).'" />' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm trying to do two things, modify it so that it only runs if the product is missing a manually set meta description, and make it pull the first 2 sentences instead of the first 1.

Impossible?

Comment: you dont have to start ever line with  **<?php** !

Comment: and please indent your code a little bit

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to do two things, modify it so that it only runs if the product is missing a manually set meta description, and make it pull the first 2 sentences instead of the first 1.
>   Impossible?

Yes, it's impossible. Because, if the product description is empty you simply can't pull two sentences from it. Not even one ;)

Notes:

- you don't need PHP tags on every line
- your if-syntax works, but is not common
- fetch the description only once, not 4 times from the registry
- compare with empty, to test if a description is set
- if not set, print "No Description."
- if set, get two sentences
- to fetch two sentences, i added the function teaser() it's from somewhere on SO

--

```
<?php
if (Mage::registry('current_product'))
{
    $metadescription = $this->description();        

    if ($metadescription === '') {
        $description = Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription();
        $twoSentences = teaser($description, 2);

        echo '<meta name="description" content="'.htmlspecialchars($twoSentences).'" />';
    }
}

function teaser($body, $sentencesToDisplay = 2)
{
    $nakedBody = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',strip_tags($body));
    $sentences = preg_split('/(\.|\?|\!)(\s)/',$nakedBody);

    if (count($sentences) <= $sentencesToDisplay)
        return $nakedBody;

    $stopAt = 0;
    foreach ($sentences as $i => $sentence) {
        $stopAt += strlen($sentence);

        if ($i >= $sentencesToDisplay - 1)
            break;
    }

    $stopAt += ($sentencesToDisplay * 2);

    return trim(substr($nakedBody, 0, $stopAt));
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I meant if the meta description field is empty. Like if I put something in the meta description field, use it, and if I didn't put something in the meta desc field then pull the sentences from the description and strip special characters.

Comment: I've updated the code accordingly. Please take a look. If a meta description is set for the product it gets set automatically. If there is no meta description, then the product description is fetched and the first two sentences are split off, stripped and inserted into the meta tag as description.